# Reduce Code Complexity for Dict of Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Need your help please. I have the following method:

```py
def edit_data(self, **kwargs: dict) -> bool:
        func_map = {
            'supID': self.po_xml.change_supplier_id,
            'uniID': self.po_xml.change_university_id,
            'creds': self.po_xml.change_sender_credentials,
            'billAdd': self.po_xml.change_bill_address,
            'shipAdd': self.po_xml.change_ship_address,
            'conAdd': self.po_xml.change_contact_address,
            'lineItems': self.po_xml.change_line_items,
            'ordNo': self.po_xml.change_order_number,
        }
        try:
            dict_only = ['billAdd', 'shipAdd', 'conAdd', ]
            for key, value in kwargs.items():
                # run the function for that key
                if key not in func_map.keys():
                    raise LookupError(f'Error in {key}, not a valid function')
                if type(value) == dict and \
                        key not in dict_only and \
                        not func_map[key](**value):
                    raise LookupError(
                        'Something went wrong, check your variables.')
                elif key in dict_only and \
                        not func_map[key](value):
                    raise LookupError(
                        'Something went wrong, check your variables.')
                elif type(value) in [str, list] and \
                        not func_map[key](value):
                    raise LookupError(
                        'Somethin went wrong, check your variable')
            return True
        except LookupError as ie:
            log.error(ie)
            return False
```

In essence `edit_data` receives several types of inputs (i.e., str, list, dict) and returns True if all of them succeeds. All functions defined above return False if it fails to update, thus triggering a `LookupError`.

I know there's a way to reduce its complexity further but I'm not too familiar how. Is there some `functools` magic I should know to help on this?